# Computing second-degree adjacency matrix in directed network

Tags: r, for-loop, network-programming, adjacency-matrix

I have a directed network and I'm trying to construct a second-degree adjacency matrix. 
Suppose the network consists of people looking at each other. From the adjacency matrix I know who looks at whom.
For second degree I mean this: for each person, is him looked at by at least one of the people I look at?
Then I would like to attach this second-degree adjacency matrix to the initial one.

The following code is a reproducible example of what I've been trying to do, it works, but given the size of my matrices it might take several days to compute:

```
t <- new("dgCMatrix"
, i = c(3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L)
, p = c(0L, 2L, 6L, 9L, 11L, 12L)
, Dim = c(5L, 5L)
, Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL)
, x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
, factors = list()
)

a <- numeric(length = 5) #create vector for the loop
b <- numeric(length = 5) #create vector to be filled and then binded

for (y in 1:5){   #example with person 1

  for (i in 1:5){   

    for (j in 1:5){

        if (t[i,j] == 1 & t[j,y] == 1){a[j] <- 1} 
         else {a[j] <- 0}
    }    #if the ones that i looks at, do look at person 1

    if (sum(a) >= 1){b[i] <-  1} else {b[i] <- 0} # if at least one of the people i looks at, looks at 1, then b[i] = 1

}  

t <- cbind(t, b)

}
```

This is the output, and it is the desired one:

```
5 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
[[ suppressing 10 column names ‘’, ‘’, ‘’ ... ]]

[1,] . 1 . . . . 1 . 1 1
[2,] . 1 . 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
[3,] . 1 1 1 . 1 1 1 1 1
[4,] 1 . 1 . . . 1 1 1 .
[5,] 1 1 1 . . . 1 1 1 1
```

It's not computationally intensive, just incredibly long. I had it running for 3 hours and it hadn't completed 1% of the process yet.

Does anyone know a better, faster way of doing this?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is likely to be much faster, but the result does not have the same `dimnames` attribute.

First, the code in the question. The original matrix `t` is saved to be used later.

```
t_save <- t    # save this for later

a <- numeric(length = 5) #create vector for the loop
b <- numeric(length = 5) #create vector to be filled and then binded

for (y in 1:5){   #example with person 1
  for (i in 1:5){   
    for (j in 1:5){
      if (t[i,j] == 1 & t[j,y] == 1){a[j] <- 1} 
      else {a[j] <- 0}
    }    #if the ones that i looks at, do look at person 1
    if (sum(a) >= 1){b[i] <-  1} else {b[i] <- 0} # if at least one of the people i looks at, looks at 1, then b[i] = 1
  }  
  t <- cbind(t, b)
}
result1 <- t
```

Now the other code giving equivalent results. The original `t` is retrieved from `t_saved`. And there is no need to create the vector `a`.

```
t <- t_save

b <- integer(length = 5)
t2 <- matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(t), ncol = ncol(t))
for (y in 1:5){   #example with person 1
  for (i in 1:5){
    b[i] <- any(t[i, ] & t[, y])
  }  
  t2[, y] <- as.integer(b)
}
result2 <- cbind(t, t2)
```

Compare both results and see that the only difference are the dim names.

```
all.equal(result1, result2)
#[1] "Attributes: < Component “Dimnames”: Component 2: Modes: character, NULL >"              
#[2] "Attributes: < Component “Dimnames”: Component 2: Lengths: 10, 0 >"                      
#[3] "Attributes: < Component “Dimnames”: Component 2: target is character, current is NULL >"
```

So, don't check the attributes.

```
all.equal(result1, result2, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

**Edit.**

Another option is to use R's matrix multiplication.

```
t <- t_save

t2 <- t %*% t
t2[t2 > 0] <- 1L
result3 <- cbind(t, t2)
all.equal(result2, result3)
#[1] TRUE
```

## Benchmarks.

The 3 methods above can be written as functions with one argument only, the sparse matrix. In the question that matrix is named `t`, in the functions' definitions it will be `A`.

```
f1 <- function(A){
  n <- nrow(A)
  a <- numeric(length = n) #create vector for the loop
  b <- numeric(length = n) #create vector to be filled and then binded

  for (y in seq_len(n)){   #example with person 1
    for (i in seq_len(n)){   
      for (j in seq_len(n)){
        if (A[i,j] == 1 & A[j,y] == 1){a[j] <- 1} 
        else {a[j] <- 0}
      }    #if the ones that i looks at, do look at person 1
      if (sum(a) >= 1){b[i] <-  1} else {b[i] <- 0} # if at least one of the people i looks at, looks at 1, then b[i] = 1
    }  
    A <- cbind(A, b)
  }
  A
}

f2 <- function(A){
  n <- nrow(A)
  t2 <- matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(A), ncol = ncol(A))
  b <- numeric(length = n) #create vector to be filled and then binded
  for (y in seq_len(n)){   #example with person 1
    for (i in seq_len(n)){
      b[i] <- +any(A[i, ] & A[, y])
    }  
    t2[, y] <- b
  }
  cbind(A, t2)
}

f3 <- function(A){
  t2 <- A %*% A
  t2[t2 > 0] <- 1L
  cbind(A, t2)
}
```

Now the tests. In order to time them, I will use package `microbenchmark`.

```
library(microbenchmark)

mb <- microbenchmark(
  f1 = f1(t),
  f2 = f2(t),
  f3 = f3(t),
  times = 10
)

print(mb, order = "median")
#Unit: milliseconds
# expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#   f3  2.35833  2.646116  3.354992  2.702440  3.452346  6.795902    10 a  
#   f2  8.02674  8.062097  8.332795  8.280234  8.398213  9.087690    10  b 
#   f1 52.08579 52.120208 55.150915 53.949815 57.413373 61.919080    10   c
```

The matrix multiply function `f3` is clearly the fastest.
The second test will be run with a bigger matrix.

```
t_save <- t

for(i in 1:5){
  t <- cbind(t, t)
  t <- rbind(t, t)
}
dim(t)
#[1] 160 160
```

And will only test `f2` and `f3`.

```
mb_big <- microbenchmark(
  f2 = f2(t),
  f3 = f3(t),
  times = 10
)

print(mb_big, order = "median")
#Unit: milliseconds
# expr        min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval cld
#   f3    15.8503    15.94404    16.23394    16.07454    16.19684    17.88267    10  a 
#   f2 10682.5161 10718.67824 10825.92810 10777.95263 10912.53420 11051.10192    10   b
```

Now the difference is impressive.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. I didn't know how to use the "any" function. this actually allows to get rid of one of the for loops. Could you please explain how that +any works? I can't find the meaning of the +

Comment: @Antonio The `+(logical_condition)` is a hack. It's equivalent to `as.integer(logical_condition)` but a little bit faster, enough to make a difference when the data sets are big, that's why I used it.

Comment: @Antonio Sorry, just tested what I said in the previous comment. The difference is so small I don't believe it will justify the code obscurity. Also, moved the coercion from logical to integer to outside the inner loop.

Comment: that's fine, thanks a lot. I'll try and run it on the big data now

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't entirely see how multiplying the matrices provides the "at least one" condition, but that's because of my poor skills with matrices' math.